# Mod_rewrite not working properly

Tags: url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this in my `.htaccess` file...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/invite$ /invite.html
```

It's meant to let a user access this url:

```
http://mysite.com/invite
```

and display the `invite.html` page. I don't want to redirect the user, but just show them the `invite.html` page from a better looking URL.

When I browse to `http://mysite.com/invite` though, I get a 404 not found error.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I've tried looking at tutorials for using mod_rewrite but I seem to be doing what they're telling me too...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there should be a `/` in that `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^invite$ invite.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that `AllowOverride All` is set for the directory where the .htaccess file lies? Else the file might be ignored.

If this isn't the case, you should check out Apache's log files for more hints (`/var/log/apache` on Linux).

Comment: I'm on shared hosting so I don't think I can view the Apache logs, and I can't see my own account specific logs anywhere either.

Comment: Ah! I found my logs in cPanel, I have loads of lines reading: `File does not exist: /home/myuser/public_html/invite`. Which doesn't make sense to me, from what I know `/invite` doesn't need to exist as it's what I'm trying to make...

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a RewriteCond directive. That's the one that does the actual testing `Cond`ition to match a URL. The RewriteRule is invoked only when one or more RewriteConds are matched.

Comment: I don't think that's accurate, you can have `RewriteRule` without `RewriteCond`